# ClearContents in Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem with ClearContents in Worksheet_Change as it keep ClearContents of the range and doesn't allow me for data entry. i want ClearContents to done only one time
would you help me with that
the code I use below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.EnableEvents = False

 If Range("A6") = "Semi Auto" Then
   Range("E5:L5").ClearContents
   Range("E6:L6").Formula = Range("E14:L14").Formula
 End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: When do you want this to occur? When the value in `A6` changes?

Answer (score 0):

This one will only trigger, if the change is concerning `Range("A6")`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A6")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Range("A6") = "Semi Auto" Then
        Range("E5:L5").ClearContents
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you , it seems i simplified my requirement. actually i have multilabel change events will happen in the sheet i.e. A6, A9 and A12, and each each one of them will have 3 options of value to be changed i.e. "Auto" , "Semi Auto" and "Manual" and of course for each change there are specific action to be done.

Comment: @welrayes - `If Intersect(Target, Range("A12"),Range("A9"), Range("A6"))` and then with `If-ElseIf`

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change

- When you copy the code into the sheet module, the second solution will be 'active'. It is the `Play` solution, which you should use to explore how the `Worksheet Change` event behaves.
- When done testing, delete it or rename it, and then rename the first, the `Real` solution, to `Worksheet_Change` without the `1`.
- This will only work if you're manually changing the values in `A6`, which also includes the change via dropdown or VBA code. If you have a formula in `A6` this will not work.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A6")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not IsError(Range("A6")) Then
            If Range("A6") = "Semi Auto" Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                On Error GoTo SafeExit
                Range("E5:L5").ClearContents
                Range("E6:L6").Formula = Range("E14:L14").Formula
                On Error GoTo 0
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    GoTo ProcExit

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A6")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not IsError(Range("A6")) Then
            If Range("A6") = "Semi Auto" Then
                MsgBox "Semi Auto."
            Else
                MsgBox "Not Semi Auto."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Is error value."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Not cell ""A6""."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you , it seems i simplified my requirement. actually  i have multilabel change events will happen in the sheet i.e. A6, A9 and A12, and each each one of them will have 3 options of value to be changed  i.e. "Auto" , "Semi Auto"  and "Manual" and of course  for each change there are specific  action to be done.

Comment: Well, you have learned that `Target` is a vital part. Now you can write three such `If` blocks one below the other, one for each cell, and instead of the inner `If` statement, use e.g. `Select Case Range("A6")` and for each case do what you had in mind e.g. `Case "Auto"`... `Case "Semi Auto"`... `Case "Manual"`...